# Python : saving variables from a text file created

Tags: python

I have been trying to split lines from a file and save that split data into variables without success.

My code is now like this:

```
cur = db.cursor() 
query = """INSERT INTO xxxx (var1, var2) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
with open('data.txt') as f:
    da = f.readlines()
    for line in da:
        values = (v1,v2)
        cur.execute(query,values)
```

But it doesn't work as I want.

My request is if any of you can help me to get from `data.txt` the values needed and saved to variables to be able to send them as a query to the database.

`data.txt` has now this:

```
0013a200419e323b <=>€#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#
0013a200419e323b <=>€#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#
```

So `var1` has to be equal to `0013a200419e323b` and `var2` to `<=>€#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#`

Comment: What is your separator and which are the desired values in the example?

Comment: unrelated but you can just iterate over `f`

Comment: Have you tried `line.split('<=>')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to split once on white space:

```
with open('data.txt') as f: 
    for line in f: # can iterate over f, no need for readlines
       values = line.split(None, 1) # splits on first whitespace only
       cur.execute(query,values)
```

You will get a list containing the two substrings you want:

```
In [13]: s="0013a200419e323b <=>€#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#"

In [14]: s.split(None,1)
Out[14]: ['0013a200419e323b', '<=>\xe2\x82\xac#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#']
In [15]: var1,var2 = s.split(None,1)
In [16]: var1
Out[16]: '0013a200419e323b'
In [17]: var2
Out[17]: '<=>\xe2\x82\xac#356894040#XBEE#0#STR:XBee frame#BAT:1#'
```

Comment: Hi! Really thanks for your answer. I am not able to test it now but tomorrow morning ( Spain here ) will. Will ofc update.